# why am i getting dbunit noclassdeffounderror databaseconnection?

Tags: java, database-connection, noclassdeffounderror, dbunit

in a helper class to my junit test classes, i create a new DataBaseconnection from dbunit to my h2databaseconnection:

```
IDatabaseConnection dBUnitConnection = new DatabaseConnection(h2con);
```

and try to run it with "dbunit-2.5.0.jar" in my classpath, i get the following errormessage:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection
```

i don't know whats going wrong. I compile and run it with eclipse which works, but i want to run the junit test from command line so i try the

`java -cp ".;./../libs/*;./libs/dbunit-2.5.0.jar;" org.junit.runner.junitcore testclass`

which should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classpath may be incomplete, it looks like your database driver jar is missing.
(A NoClassDefFoundError can also be caused by a problem while initializing a class, e.g. an exception, this is different from a ClassNotFoundException).

Check your classpath against your Java build path in Eclipse.

**Edit:**

Moved my comment, which pointed to the real cause to the answer:

Having a look at the source of `org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection`, it could also be a missing slf4j jar. dbunit uses slf4j for logging and tries to initialize the slf4j classes when the `DatabaseConnection` is initialized.

Comment: i will try, but shouldn't the dbunit-2.5.0.jar at least solve the databaseconnection issue?

Comment: Having a look at the source of `org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection`, it could also be a missing slf4j jar. dbunit uses slf4j for logging and tries to initialize the slf4j classes when the `DatabaseConnection` is initialized.

Comment: i use the log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

remove the double quotes from the classpath definition:

```
java -cp .;./libs/dbunit-2.5.0.jar org.junit.runner.junitcore testclass
```

Comment: Tried but didn't change

Comment: @MidgarZolom do you run on a windows or ix based system? The libs folder is existend in your actual working dir and it contailns the jar?

Comment: i run currently under windows

Comment: @MidgarZolom The libs folder is existend in your actual working dir and it contailns the jar?

Comment: i have all jars in my libs folder my actual working dir is /server/bin, the libs folder is /server/libs

Comment: Then you have to change your classpath to `.;../libs/dbunit-2.5.0.jar`